# PHP line break not writing correctly

Tags: php, file-io, newline

I have a file that I have to read in and modify in PHP, and so I read it in, explode it by new lines, modify what I need, then re-stick it together re-adding newlines via `\n`.

However, it seems to be outputting them as `\r\\n` for some reason. The file before any modification has new lines as \r\n which seems to work fine. Only when I add the new lines via `\n` does it break into `\r\\n`.

Also after some reading, I tried the newlines as `\r\n` instead of just `\n`, but that outputs as `\r\\r\\n`. Any ideas guys? Thanks a lot! If you need to see anything else or require more info, just ask.

The code that add's the new lines is here:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i<count($tmp);$i++){
        $tmpstr .= $tmp[$i];
        if(count($tmp)-1 != $i){
            $tmpstr .= '\r\n';
        }
    }
```

It adds newlines at the end of all but the last line, that seems to be working fine except for the wrong characters.

Comment: are you splitting your string up with `explode("\n", $string);`? If so, just split it up with  `explode("\r\n", $string);`, or do a str_replace("\r","", $string);

Comment: Replace your loop with: `$tmpstr = implode("\r\n", $tmp);`. [Ta-da!](http://codepad.org/ceLz3KnK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `$tmpstr .= '\r\n';`
To: `$tmpstr .= "\r\n" # Use double quotes`;

Comment: Thanks that worked, are there any other times I need to be careful of quotes vs apostrophes?

Comment: theres a great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php

Answer (score 2):

you have to use double quotes `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [predefined constant PHP_EOL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) (End Of Line):

```
$tmpstr .= PHP_EOL;
```